# really weird but maybe you know more about trasientpropertyvalue exception in android studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, interface, transient-failure

When I run app in android studio and complete some informations and click on the button $pay my App shows
(org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValue Exception: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : net.holosen.online shop.models.invoices.Transaction.invoice ->)
and I don`t know why.

I tried to run App and complete the informations but it showed me an unknown error.

Comment: I really want to solve this problem but I don't know how?

Comment: If you need something more I can share with you or anything else.